# How to calculate a bullet's trajectory on an isometric plane?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, isometric

I'd need some help from an "iso guru". I am fiddling on a game where there are two cannons placed on an isometric grid. When one cannon fires a bullet, it should fly in a curved trajectory, like shown below. While this would be an easy task on an x/y plane, I have no clue how to calculate a curved path (with variable height) on an isometric plane.

Could someone point me into the right direction please? I'd need to fire bullets from one field to any given other, while the bullets' flying altitude (the "strength" of the curve) depends on the given shot power.

Any hints? :(

Image: http://postimg.org/image/6lcqnwcrr/

Comment: What do you mean "an isometric plane"? Isometric projection is simply a projection from 3D to 2D; it has nothing to do with the underlying physics. Just do a 3D ballistics equation then project the resulting 3D coordinates.

Comment: As I entered with the keywords above, I'm using 2D graphics ONLY (using Corona and LUA), so basically I think I'd need a method to draw a curve (with variable height) from one iso field to any given other.

Comment: The _graphics_ have nothing to do with the _physics_. You can do the projectile equation in 3D then project those coordinates from 3D to 2D via an isometric projection. This is also how '3D' graphics are done, since screens are 2D. (Also, it's "Lua", not "LUA")

Answer (score 2):

This may help. The trajectory function takes some trajectory parameters (velocity, elevation, starting position and gravity) and  returns a function that calcs the y position from the x position in world space.
The converter returns a function that converts between world and screen co-ords for a given projection angle.
What follows is an example of it being used to calculate the trajectory for some points in screen space. 
It's really for indication purposes. It has a bunch of potential divide by zeroes but it generates trajectories that look ok for sensible elevations, projections and velocities.

```
-- A trajectory in world space
function trajectory(v,elevation,x0,y0,g)
    x0 = x0 or 0
    y0 = y0 or 0
    local th = math.rad(elevation or 45)
    g = g or 9.81

    return function(x)
        x = x-x0
        local a = x*math.tan(th)
        local b = (g*x^2)/(2*(v*math.cos(th))^2)
        return y0+a-b
    end
end

-- convert between screen and world
function converter(iso)
    iso = math.rad(iso or 0)
    return function(toscreen,x,y)
        if toscreen then
            y = y+x*math.sin(iso)
            x = x*math.cos(iso)
        else
            x = x/math.cos(iso)
            y = y-x*math.sin(iso)
        end
        return x,y
    end
end

-- velocity 60m/s at an angle of 70 deg
t = trajectory(60,70,0,0)

-- iso projection of 30 deg
c = converter(30)

-- x in screen co-ords
for x = 0,255 do
    local xx = c(false,x,0) -- x in world co-ords
    local y = t(xx) -- y in world co-ords
    local _,yy = c(true,xx,y) -- y in screen co-ords
    local _,y0 = c(true,xx,0) --ground in screen co-ords
    yy = math.floor(yy) -- not needed 
    if yy>y0 then print(x,yy) end -- if it's above ground
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no lateral forces you can use the 2D equation for ballistic motion in XZ plane (so y=0 at all time), then rotate via a 3D transformation around z axis to account for actual orientation of canon in 3D space. This transformation matrix is very simple, you can unfold the multiplication (write out the terms multiplied) to get the 3D equations.